# Cannot copy dist folder created with nuitka to any other location

Tags: python, python-3.7, nuitka

I created a small program (including some Qt5) with python and then used nuitka to create an exe using the following command line:

```
python -m nuitka --standalone --follow-imports --enable-plugin=qt-plugins --mingw64 rs_main.py
```

This results in a rs_main.dist folder in which are many pyd and dll files and also an rs_main.exe. Executing this exe works fine

However I tried copying this folder to other locations of my computer such as:
`c:\Program files\`, `c:\`, `desktop` and even `Downloads` but the exe keeps crashing.

I found some info in the eventviewer which tells me:

```
Faulting application name: rs_main.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5cb4928c
Faulting module name: python37.dll, version: 3.7.3150.1013, time stamp: 0x5c9954b1
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000000000002324d
Faulting process id: 0x77cc
Faulting application start time: 0x01d4f44b3ff0a8fe
Faulting application path: 
D:\Users\hillebr\Downloads\test\rs_main.dist\rs_main.exe
Faulting module path: 
D:\Users\hillebr\Downloads\test\rs_main.dist\python37.dll
```

Does anyone have an idea where I should be looking next?

Comment: Same here, using last stable nuitka version for win64.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: No, I stopped of using nuitka for now, many problems.